# including jquery in pug template

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, pug, web-deployment

I am trying to include the jquery library to expose some of its functionality. I have followed tutorials, looks at examples, and I get a weird error which clearly indicates I am not loading the module properly.

error:

```
10|             script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous")
    11|             script
  > 12|                 $(document).ready(function(){
------------------------^
    13|                 $("button").click(function(){
    14|                     $("p").hide();
    15|                 });

unexpected text "$(doc"
```

Now i thought I could simply import the script with the classic script tag, but it is not working. This is my base templates header.

```
doctype html
html
    head  
        block head  
            meta(charset=utf-8)
            meta(viewport='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/testTables.css')
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/tableStyles.css')
            script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous")
            script
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("p").hide();
                });
                });
```

Now to clarify, this is stored in my views folder in the root directory of my project. I am using nodeJS and express. I have the jquery package as a dependency as well. My project is also serving from the root/public folder as defined by here.

```
//all the static assets are being served from public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

If someone could give me a hand that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `.` dot after the script declaration when you have a block of text in a tag.

```
script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    });
```

The pug documentation [here](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) explains it very well.